# How do I show the form for adding a node as block?

Tags: nodes, hooks, blocks

I have a content type with the title and name fields. How can I the form for adding a node as block, in the front page?

I am using Drupal 7.

```
function mail_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['mail_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('backend info left block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}


function mail_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'mail_block') {
    $match = TRUE;
    $types = array('mailin_list_node_form' => 1);
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
      $type = $node->type;
      if (isset($types[$type])) {
        $match = FALSE;
      }
    }

    $contact_node = node_load($node);

    drupal_get_form($node);
    $block = array(
      'subject' => t(''),
      'content' => $content,
    );

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the teaser of the node to be displayed? Or the full node? Or do you mean the node add form?

Comment: i mean node addform

Comment: As side note, it is useless to pass an empty string to `t()`: An empty string is an empty string in any language. There is no need to translate an empty string; just use `''`, instead of `t('')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function mail_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['mail_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('backend info left block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}


function mail_block_view($block_name = '') {
  global $user;

  if ($block_name == 'mail_block') {
    // This is required if you want to show this block even if user profile page.
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

    // Create a node for the content type.
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->name = $user->name;
    $node->type = 'CONTENT_TYPE_NAME';
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    // Create the form.
    $form = drupal_get_form('CONTENT_TYPE_NAME_node_form', $node);

    $block = array(
      'subject' => t(''),
      'content' => drupal_render($form),
    );

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [node_add()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7):

```
$content = node_add($type);
```

or:

```
$content = drupal_get_form($type . '_node_form', $node);
```

Also, please keep in mind that `node_load()` changed in D7. You should use it like this:

```
node_load($nid);
```

Comment: you mean node_load_multiple()

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim I'm pretty sure he means `node_load`...your code is: `node_load($node)`, which might have been valid in Drupal 6 but not in Drupal 7

Comment: @Clive In Drupal 6, it would work if `$node` is an array; in Drupal 7, the first argument must be the node ID, as you said.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno I've forgotten most of D6 to be honest ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code.

```
    $types = array('mailin_list_node_form' => 1);
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
      $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
      $type = $node->type;
      if (isset($types[$type])) {
        $match = FALSE;
      }
    }
```

In Drupal 7, the first argument of [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) is the node ID, not an array. The full code snippet is unnecessary complex. All that code can be replaced with a call to [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7), and to check the content type of a node you just compare `$node->type` with a string.

```
    $contact_node = node_load($node);
```

You are passing to `node_load()` an object you already obtained from `node_load()`. First, `node_load()` doesn't accept an object, in Drupal 7 (nor would it accept a node as first argument, in Drupal 6); secondly, it doesn't make sense to call `node_load()` when you have already obtained a node object from that function.
You initialize `$contact_node`, but that variable is not used from the rest of your code.

```
    drupal_get_form($node);
```

The parameters passed to [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) are wrong; the first argument passed is the form ID, and you didn't pass that argument to the function.
The result returned from the function is not saved; probably you were supposed to save it in the `$content` variable.

I would use code similar to the following one.

```
function mail_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ($delta == 'mail_block' && ($node = menu_get_object()) && $node->type == 'YOUR CONTENT TYPE') {
    $block = array(
      'subject' => '',
      'content' => drupal_get_form('YOUR CONTENT TYPE FORM ID', $node),
    );

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Replace `'YOUR CONTENT TYPE'` with the ID of the content type, and `'YOUR CONTENT TYPE FORM ID'` with the form ID for the form, which is normally similar to `<your_content_type>_node_form`, where `<your_content_type>` is the string you used for `'YOUR CONTENT TYPE FORM ID'`.

To notice that it is not necessary to pass an empty string to `t()` because an empty string is still an empty string in all the languages; there is no need to translate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock)

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or
>   node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for
>   including forms on panels.

As its dev in D7 make sure you read the [Issues for Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/issues/formblock?status=All&categories=All)

Answer (score 0):

```
function mail_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'mail_block') {
    $form = drupal_get_form('mailin_list_node_form');
    $block = array(
        'subject' => t(''),
        'content' => drupal_render($form),
    );
    return $block;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used this code but it return me an error: "Undefined variable: node in mail_block_view()."

Comment: i think that the name of content type is wrong

Comment: are you sure your content type's machine name is called "mailin_list"? Not "mailing_list"? (notice the g after mailin). I got it from your original question.

Comment: yes iam sure its called "mailin_list" ,

Comment: now i think all problem in the $block line

Comment: The problem with the code is that the call to `drupal_get_form('mailin_list_node_form')` is missing an argument that is necessary: the node object. Without that, Drupal doesn't know for which node the form is being shown.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you are right. i have tried to do this and it resolved . function mail_block_view($block_name = '') {
     module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  if ($block_name == 'mail_block') {
    $type = 'mailin_list';
    
//    $form = drupal_get_form($type);
    $form = node_add('mailin_list');
    $block = array(
        'subject' => t(''),
        'content' => drupal_render($form),
    );
    return $block;
  }
  
}

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. Yes, drupal_get_form should get the node object as a second parameter. Glad you got it working though, sorry again for wasting your time.